# An algebra which is a direct sum of simple sub-bimodules over a subalgebra

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, modules, noncommutative-rings, projective-modules

Let $A$ be an infinite-dimensional noncommutative algebra over a field, let $B$ be an infinite-dimensional subalgebra of $A$, and let $A$ be a direct sum of projective simple $B$-sub-bimodules. Then can one conclude that $A$, or indeed $B$, is a semisimple ring?

EDIT: I should highlight that I am interested only in the case where $A$ and $B$ are infinite-dimensional algebras.

Comment: It is B that must be semisimple and I guess separable

Comment: Ah ok, so to get this straight: From the assumptions above on $A$ and $B$, we can conclude that $B$ is a semisimple ring?

Comment: I think so.  B will be a semisimple bimodule and the simple summands are a subset of those appearing in A. Thus B is a projective B-B bimodule and hence separable. Any separable algebra over a field is semisimple.  I'm assuming that in these bimodules the left and right actions of k agree which I guess is fine since this is true for the bimodule structure on A.

Comment: Great! Please put this as an answer and I will accept it!

Comment: I probably won't have a chance to write a detailed answer until later.

Comment: Sure, no problem!

Comment: I believe B must be finite dimensional in your setup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@BugsBunny answered the original version of the question.  I'll answer the new version.  The algebra $B$ must be finite dimensional and semisimple under these hypothesis, and even stronger, it must be separable meaning that it remains semisimple even under base extension.

Let $B^{e}=B\otimes_k B^{op}$ be the enveloping algebra. Note that (left) $B^e$-modules equal $B$-$B$-bimodules in which the left and right actions of $k$ coincide. In particular $A$ and $B$ are $B^e$-modules.

Recall that $B$ is separable  over $k$ if $B$ is a projective left $B^e$-module.  This is well known to be equivalent to $B$ being finite dimensional over $k$ and for each field extension $L/K$, the algebra $L\otimes_k B$ is semisimple.  All these things can be found in Pierce's book.

Now under your assumption, $A$ is a direct sum of simple $B^e$-modules that are projective.  Thus $A$ is a semisimple $B^e$-module and hence the same is true for its $B^e$-submodule $B$.  Moreover, if $S$ is a simple $B^e$-submodule of $B$, then it must be nontrivial under the one of the projections of $A$ onto a simple $B^e$-summand and so $S$ is isomorphic to one of the simple $B^e$-summands in $A$  by Schur's lemma.  Therefore, $B$ is a direct sum of projective $B^e$-modules and hence is projective.  Thus $B$ is separable over $K$ and hence finite dimensional and semisimple (even after base change).

So your desired situation cannot occur if $B$ is infinite dimensional over $k$.

If you drop the projective hypothesis you could take $B$ a finite direct product of simple $k$-algebras at least one of which is infinite dimensional and take $A=B$ and $A$ will be a finite direct sum of simple $B$-bimodules. You can even make $B$ finitely presented as a $k$-algebra.

Comment: Ok, so now I see the issue. I meant projective as a left module, and projective as a right module, not projective as a bimodule. But as I wrote it indicates projective as a bimodule. But it's too late to change to change it now, so thanks a lot for the answer!

Comment: Maybe you should ask a question about the specific algebras you are interested in.  You want A a direct sum of simple B-bimodules and B projective as a left and right B-module?

Comment: I meant A projective as a left and right B-module.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I want. Is there anything interesting that can be said in this case about the $B$ , or $A$, or their modules?

Comment: What if A=B and B is a finite direct product of simple rings? That's a fairly general situation.

Comment: Yes, I guess there is little one can say at that level of generality.

Comment: I don't understand your answer. What is about $k={\mathbb Q}$, $B= {\mathbb Q}\times {\mathbb C}$ and $A=B[x]$?

Comment: @BugsBunny I believe the issue with your counterexample is writing A as a direct sum of projective simple B-bimodules.  I dont think your B is  a projective B-bimodules.  There is a big difference between projective as a one sided module and as a bimodule.  If you take $B\otimes_{\mathbb Q} B$ it contains $\mathbb C\otimes_{\mathbb Q} \mathbb C$ as a summand which is some fairly huge and complicated commutative algebra which is uncountably dimension over $\mathbb C$.  Is it semisimple?

Comment: The OP wasn't clear what kind of bimodules are allowed.  Since he is taking about k-algebras I interpreted bimodules as $B^e$-modules.  I am not convinced of you take $k=\mathbb Q$ and $B=\mathbb C=A$ that $B$ is a projective $\mathbb C\otimes_Q \mathbb C=B^e$-module.  But since projectivity depends on the category of bimodules the OP should have been clearer.

Comment: Yes, I see. Of course, you are right. Thank you for explaining!

Comment: @BugsBunny, actually I was quite confused for a while why your counterexample doesn't work and even doublechecked the proof in Pierce.  So I now understand things better

Answer (score 4):

No. Take any $A$ and take the ground field $k=k1_A$ as $B$.

Comment: For latecomers, please note that this answered the original version of the question which has since changed.

Comment: It did not change that much :-))